# Custom textarea field with tagging users in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I need a custom text area field and when i type @, I have to tag users (i.e) autocomplete users like in facebook. I am new to angular js and i would like to get help on how to achieve this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to at least google your question before asking them. You are not the first one with this issue.

This was literally the first google result: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mention